# Compute of randomly sampling matrix

Tags: r, matrix, mean, sampling

I have a matrix of 30 rows:

```
set.seed(1234)
m = matrix(rnorm(300), 30)
```

I want to randomly divide it into three sub-matrix (each one will contain 10 rows) and calculate the colMeans of each sub-groups.

How I can do it?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to your questions, `set.seed(1234); matrix(rnorm(300), 30)` for example. And in most cases, adding the expected output is helpful.

Comment: `lapply(split(sample(1:30), ceiling(1:30/10)), function(i) colSums(m[i,]))`

Answer (score 1):

I would use sample to get the `random` grouping, `rowsum` to get the group column sums and then divide by 3 to get the mean.

Here,

```
rowsum(myMat, sample(rep(1:3, length.out=nrow(myMat)), nrow(myMat))) / 3
```

The length.out argument to `rep` assures that `sample` will have 30 elements to permute, 10 1s, 10 2s, and 10 3s. `sample(rep(1:3, length.out=nrow(myMat)), nrow(myMat))` returns a random permutation of this set of integers that `rowsums` uses for the grouping.

The first five columns of this calculation returns

```
        [,1]       [,2]        [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
1 -1.5317639 -2.4137994  0.88905767 0.5783829  0.2593529
2 -0.6781386 -0.5701739 -0.03524136 0.3623384  1.4022571
3 -0.7543473 -2.5322095  0.53218802 0.1745588 -0.5748851
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
matrix(rnorm(300), 30)
```